# Should I write 'StackExchange' or 'Stack Exchange' (or just plain old SE)?

Tags: discussion

Same with StackOverflow.  Or Stack Overflow.  Or SO.  I don't know if it's proper to run the words together or not when written.  It often appears like that around the site, but in some meta questions I see the words separated by a space.

Comment: This looks more appropriate on Meta to me, since it's about the site itself... Voting to migrate.

Comment: I reasoned that the principle behind the question belonged to EL&U (@rintaun! :) and hence put it there.  But I concede the point.  You're right.

Comment: Just don't mix 'em up with [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).  Ewww.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "official" names are **Stack Exchange** and **Stack Overflow**. If you go to the "About" page on each site, these are the only names that are used. In general usage, though, like you've pointed out yourself, the space appears to be optional. If you prefer to abbreviate, **SE** and **SO** are perfectly valid as well, similar to how English Language & Usage is often abbreviated as **EL&U**.

Comment: I would upvote, only I have no more votes today. :-/

Comment: @drm65 Well thanks for the support anyway. :D

Comment: Ha.  I can upvote in meta, only then you don't get any rep.  :-&

Comment: @drm65 Haha. Either way, neat. I've not posted on meta before. First time for everything, I guess, even if it's a bit roundabout. :P

Answer (score 5):

See

http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

under the heading

> #### Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name

Comment: That's all I needed!  (I was trying to find an official name)  Thanks!